# Usage of 'I would have + past tense'

Tags: verb-usage

1. I would have liked if she would have said no.
2. I would have liked if she had said no.
3. I would have liked if she'd said no.

Is it correct to use would have twice in the same sentence here? Is the contraction fine?

Comment: In any case, you need an **it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received grammar says that what is correct is "I would have liked it if she had said no."

Received grammar, however, is about formal prose, particularly formal writing. So, in any of the numerous contexts where contractions are appropriate,

"I would have liked it if she'd said no" is perfectly fine.

Finally, over the last 30 years in the US, more and more people do make statements like

"I would have liked it if she would have said no."

I recommend against it because at least some will view that formulation as ungrammatical or uneducated.